# phpmailer does not work

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have to send a mail via Gmail, but i don't know how to configure a `phpmailer`.
When I use `phpmailer` it gives me an error that has not been authenticated but email and password are true.

Here is the code:

```
require '../class.phpmailer.php';

try {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                 //New instance, with exceptions enabled

    $body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
    $body             = preg_replace('/\\\\/','', $body); //Strip backslashes

    $mail->IsSMTP();                             // tell the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                    // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 25;                      // set the SMTP server port
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";        // SMTP server
    $mail->Username   = "yuliy.x.95@gmail.com";  // SMTP server username
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";            // SMTP server password

    $mail->IsSendmail();                         // tell the class to use Sendmail

    $mail->AddReplyTo("k.yuliy@yahoo.it","First Last");

    $mail->From       = "name@domain.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "First Last";

    $to = "k.yuliy@yahoo.it";

    $mail->AddAddress($to);

    $mail->Subject  = "First PHPMailer Message";

    $mail->AltBody  = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";                                            // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->WordWrap = 80;                      // set word wrap

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);

    $mail->IsHTML(true);                         // send as HTML 

    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

I get this error:

> Could not execute: /var/qmail/bin/sendmail

Comment: Have you looked at [any of these](https://www.google.com/#q=Could+not+execute%3A+%2Fvar%2Fqmail%2Fbin%2Fsendmail)?

Comment: What is the OS of the server?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that sendmail might not be getting called right, you're trying to connect to port 25.  You can't do that.  smtp.gmail.com *requires* SSL -- it's not optional.

Answer (score 0):

With the command `$mail->isSMTP()` you are selecting SMTP as the transport.

But before you send the mail, you are switching back to using a local installation of sendmail with `$mail->isSendmail()`.

Don't do it, and your current error will go away. Probably a new one might appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use port 465 for Gmail

```
$mail->Port       = 465;
```